# Xamarin android : VideoView does not call SurfaceCreated

Tags: android, user-interface, video, xamarin

I'm struggling to play a video from Assets with a VideoView and a MediaPlayer.

Build version : android 6.0.1 Marshmallow API 23

Debug Device : NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet K1

The issue : my VideoView seems to not create a surface, since the function "SurfaceCreated" is never called during debug.

Actual result : when the activity is loaded, the screen is grey and I can hear the correct sound of the video.

Here is my code :

```
public class VideoTestActivity : Activity, MediaPlayer.IOnPreparedListener, ISurfaceHolderCallback
    {
        MediaPlayer player;
        VideoView _myVideoView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.VideoTest);

            player = new MediaPlayer();

            _myVideoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.video);

            _myVideoView.Start();
            _myVideoView.SetZOrderOnTop(true); // tried from Q&A, display a grey screen

            var descriptor = Assets.OpenFd("video.mp4");// the data is correctly loaded
            player.SetDataSource(descriptor.FileDescriptor, descriptor.StartOffset, descriptor.Length);
            player.Prepare();
            player.Start();
        }


        public void OnPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            player.SetDisplay(_myVideoView.Holder); // never called
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And here is my axml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <VideoView
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/video"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I have tried/checked :

- my VideoView has a widht/height different from 0
- the descriptor is correctly loaded
- SetZOrderOnTop() has been called after Start()
- the videoView is correctly loaded by FindViewById()

I'm still searching for an anwser, but since I have checked every post-related on stackOverflow, I opened this post.

Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally i found a solution to play my video, but none to load the Surface.

Creating a raw folder was the solution.

here is the new code (other fields from the previous one are blank):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.VideoTest);

        VideoView view = (VideoView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.videoPacificRim);
            String path = "android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.pacificrim_file;
            view.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path));
            view.Start();
        }
```

I close the subject, even if the original question is not answered.